# How to find the maximum value of the expression $y=2(a-x)(x+\sqrt{x^2+b^2})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

The maximum value of the expression $y=2(a-x)(x+\sqrt{x^2+b^2})$

If we take derivative, then I am not getting anything, please guide how to proceed in such problems will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: Mathematica answers $$\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 a^2 & b=0\land a>0 \\
 b^2 & (b>0\land a\leq 0)\lor (b<0\land a\leq 0) \\
 a^2+b^2 & (b>0\land a>0)\lor (b<0\land a>0) \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
,\left\{x\to 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{a}{2} & b=0\land a>0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} \left(a-\sqrt{a^2}-2\right) & b=0\land a\leq 0 \\
 \frac{a^2-b^2}{2 a} & (b>0\land a>0)\lor (b<0\land a>0) \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right\}\right\} .$$

Answer (score 2):

Differentiation + some work:
$$
\begin{align}
y'
&=
-2\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+b^2}\right)
+2(a-x)\left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}\right) \\
&=
-2\sqrt{x^2+b^2}\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}\right)
+2(a-x)\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}\right) \\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
this implies:
$$
\sqrt{x^2+b^2}=(a-x)
$$
and you can square both sides and work out the equation.

Comment: @sultan: Have you had a chance to see my answer yet? Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt{x^2+b^2}+x=z.$ Then $\displaystyle \sqrt{x^2+b^2}-x=\frac{b^2}{z}.$

So $$y=z \bigg(2a-z+\frac{b^2}{z}\bigg)=2az-z^2+b^2=a^2+b^2-(z-b)^2\leq a^2+b^2$$

Comment: It must be $(z-a)^2$ not $(z-b)^2$ in the last line.